# View extended options that were passed into mkfs.ext4

Tags: filesystems, ext4, mkfs

I am working with two block devices in a situation where one works with a certain configuration and the other does not. I assume this must be related to subtle differences in the extended options that were passed into respective calls of `mkfs.ext4`.

How can I inspect those options for existing block devices for a detailed comparison. What other (subtle) differences could perhaps play a role?

Comment: That sounds like an [X & Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)... Please describe those "subtle differences" in behavior and the actual problems you're experiencing instead.

But the properties of a file system are encoded in the file system superblock itself as Ryan explains below, which combine with the options in `/etc/fstab` or those used in your `mount` command and kernel settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Too vague**

I need details about your problem - you're question is too general/vague. If I knew exactly what problem you were facing, I could try to give you the exact information you need. If you update your question, I'll try to help. The best I can do is provide you with general information.

**Getting ext4 information**

You can get ext4 filesystem information with `tune2fs` and `dumpe2fs`. Read their man pages for command line options.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda2
```

Comment: The general information was all that was needed. Thx.